# How to use conditional statement within child attribute of a Flutter Widget (Center Widget)

Tags: flutter, if-statement, dart, conditional-statements

So far whenever I needed to use a conditional statement within a Widget I have done the following (Using Center and Containers as simplified dummy examples):

```
new Center(
  child: condition == true ? new Container() : new Container()
)
```

Though when I tried using an if/else statement it would lead to an Dead code warning:

```
new Center(
  child: 
    if(condition == true){
      new Container();
    }else{
      new Container();
    }
)
```

Interestingly enough I tried with a switch case statement and it gives me the same warning and thus I cannot run the code. Am I doing something wrong or is it so that one cannot use if/else or switch statements without flutter thinking there is dead code?

Comment: If you want to insert a block where widgets should be instantiated you probably better build your widget in class methods

Comment: Center(
child:Builder(builder:(context){
  if(true) return widget1();
  else  return widget2();
})
)

Answer (score 480):

Actually you **can** use `if/else` and `switch` and any other statement inline in dart / flutter.

#### Use a builder

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          if (true) //
            return "tis true";

          return "anything but true";
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

#### or an immediate anonymous function

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: () {
      if (value == 1) {
        return Text('tis true');
      }
      return Text('anything but true');
    }());
  }
```

*I would heavily recommend against putting too much logic directly with your UI 'markup' but I found that type inference in Dart needs a little bit of work so it can be sometimes useful in scenarios like that.*

#### Use the ternary operator

```
condition ? Text("True") : null,
```

#### Use If or For statements or spread operators in collections

```
children: [
  ...manyItems,
  oneItem,
  if(canIKickIt)
    ...kickTheCan
  for (item in items)
    Text(item)
```

#### Use a method

```
child: getWidget()

Widget getWidget() {
  if (x > 5) ...
  //more logic here and return a Widget
```

#### EDIT - new with Dart 3.0

Dart 3.0 adds new functionality such as if-case & switch expressions in order to use pattern matching, destructuring, guard clauses.
https://dart.dev/language/patterns

#### Switch Expressions

We can now use switch as an expression.
https://dart.dev/language/branches#switch-expressions

```
child: switch (task) {
  Task_completed(:date) => Text("completed on $date"),
  Task_overdue(:priority) => Text("$priority"),
},
```

#### if-case (new to Dart 3.0)

Use if-case instead of switch when you have a single or small number of conditions to check.
https://dart.dev/language/branches#if-case

```
return ListView(children: [
  Text('header'),
  if (pair case [int x, int y]) // 
    Text('Coordinates: ($x, $y)') // 
  else
    Text('No coordinates given'),
]);
```

Comment: Just a note if anyone gets stuck, if you are using Provider to rebuild your widgets on global state change, and you are getting data via "Provider.of", your conditional statement may not be re-evaluated until some other action rebuilds your widget. You need to be getting your conditional variable via "Consumer" that is being returned to the Widget build function, then your conditional statement should be properly re-evaluated as global state changes.

Comment: One of the best things for good practices in dart/flutter

Comment: which one is better in ternary code? using `null` or empty `Container()` ?

Comment: where can u put the style in, by the immediate anonymous funtion? for exampe: style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),

Comment: I was getting an error that Column cannot contain null values for the ternary and empty Container() was a work around

Comment: This is the way if you're dealing with single child non-null view toggling!

Comment: @buncis It depends. Null is not allowed if you are inside a List<Widget>. In such situation, you can simply use if (condition) Widget() as one of the list element. If you are modifying a Widget? property, then null is the way.

Answer (score 290):

I personally use if/else statement in children with this kind of block statement. It only supports on Dart version 2.3.0 above.

if / else

```
Column(
    children: [
        if (_selectedIndex == 0) ...[
          DayScreen(),
        ] else ...[
          StatsScreen(),
        ],
    ],
 ),
```

if / else if

```
Column(
    children: [
        if (_selectedIndex == 0) ...[
          DayScreen(),
        ] else if(_selectedIndex == 1)...[
          StatsScreen(),
        ],
    ],
 ),
```

multiple widgets example

```
Column(
    children: [
        if (_selectedIndex == 0) ...[
          DayScreen(),
          AboutScreen(),
          InfoScreen(),
        ] else if(_selectedIndex == 1)...[
          HomeScreen(),
          StatsScreen(),
        ],
    ],
 ),
```

Comment: That `...[]` trick is awesome. It's a detail that no other answer mentioned, but it's very useful if you want to add multiple widgets conditionally.

Comment: does any one know this works starting from which version of flutter?

Comment: @ShadyMohamedSherif which version you are using now? I started using flutter from 1.17 and it is already working since then. This is nothing special, it's just spreading a list of widgets.

Comment: @brendan, IDK, seems kind of special since Dart won't respond to more colloquial forms of `if/else` statements in this context, including ternary, but does work correctly using a spread syntax that a lot (most?) people don't know about. My initial attempts were all trying to choose between different lists at the `children` level, not inside the `children` list.  Seems like a place for Dart to improve.

Comment: why do we need the three dots? please

Comment: you cannot just put a list into the widget tree.
you need to inline the widgets of the list into the tree, which is done by the three dots

Comment: even `...{` works, not just `...[`

Comment: @MH yes `...{` is spreading the Set, it might have warning when you have two same const Widget in the Set since Set cannot have two identical element.

Answer (score 106):

In Dart, `if/else` and `switch` are statements not expressions. They don't return a value so you can't pass them to constructor params. If you have a lot of conditional logic in your build method, then it is a good practice to try and simplify it.  For example, you can move self-contained logic to methods, and use `if/else` statements to initialize local variables which you can later use.

#### Using a method and if/else

```
Widget _buildChild() {
  if (condition) {
    return ...
  }
  return ...
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Container(child: _buildChild());
}
```

#### Using an `if/else`

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Widget child;
  if (condition) {
    child = ...
  } else {
    child = ...
  }
  return new Container(child: child);
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer! Thank you for this clarification it helped me!

Comment: What if you have a deep tree, and conditionally want to render something in the tree? Duplicate? Or will I have to split the tree somehow?

Answer (score 84):

In such a case I would recommand using the ternary operator:

`child: condition ? Container() : Center()`

and try to avoid code of the form:

`if (condition) return A else return B`

which is needlessly more verbose than the ternary operator.

But if more logic is needed you may also:

### Use the Builder widget

The [Builder widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html) is meant for allowing the use of a closure when a child widget is required:

> *A platonic widget that calls a closure to obtain its child widget.*

**It is convenient anytime you need logic to build a widget**, it avoids the need to create a dedicated function.

You use the Builder widget as the child, you provide your logic in its `builder` method:

```dart
Center(
  child: Builder(
    builder: (context) {
      // any logic needed...
      final condition = _whateverLogicNeeded();
      
      return condition
          ? Container();
          : Center();
    }
  )
)
```

The Builder provides a convenient place to hold the creational logic. It is more straightforward than the immediate anonymous function proposed by atreeon.

Also I agree that the logic should be extracted from the UI code, but when it's really UI logic it is sometimes more legible to keep it there.

Comment: this worked for me pretty well for drawer items click and updating body

Answer (score 48):

For the record, Dart 2.3 added the ability to use if/else statements in Collection literals. This is now done the following way:

```
return Column(children: <Widget>[
  Text("hello"),
  if (condition)
     Text("should not render if false"),
  Text("world")
],);
```

[Flutter Issue #28181 - Inline conditional rendering in list](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28181#issuecomment-508349651)

Comment: I have dart 2.5 but I get error running above code. It says ` this code is required to be compatible with earlier versions. try updating SDK constraints`

Comment: emmm, interesting~

Comment: Do they add for loop feature? if so how to implement it?

Comment: @Aseem https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#sdk_version_ui_as_code

Comment: Doesn't work with a single widget like `AppBar -> leading:` or `child:`

Comment: In case someone get an error about the experiment --flow-control-collections. You just need to update your pubspec.yml environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0". Then do flutter clean, and also clean the cache.

Comment: @Aseem - this is because your pubspec.yaml is probably claiming compatability with older versions of dart. Edit the sdk value to declare at least 2.3 on the low value

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

Answer (score 31):

I found out that an easy way to use conditional logic to build Flutter UI is to keep the logic outside of the UI. Here is a function to return two different colors:

```
Color getColor(int selector) {
  if (selector % 2 == 0) {
    return Colors.blue;
  } else {
    return Colors.blueGrey;
  }
}
```

The function is used below to to set the background of the CircleAvatar.

```
new ListView.builder(
  itemCount: users.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new ListTile(
          leading: new CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: getColor(index),
            child: new Text(users[index].name[0])
          ),
          title: new Text(users[index].login),
          subtitle: new Text(users[index].name),
        ),
        new Divider(height: 2.0),
      ],
    );
  },
);
```

Very neat as you can reuse your color selector function in several widgets.

Comment: I tried this and worked for me the exact way. Thanks

Answer (score 24):

### The simplest way:

```
// the ternary operator:
<conditon>
  ? Widget1()
  : Widget2()

// Or:
if (condition)
    Widget1()

// With else/ if else
if (condition1)
    Widget1()
else if (condition2)
    Widget2()
else
    Widget3(),
```

If you want to render **MULTIPLE WIDGETS for one condition**, you can use the ***spread operator*** (for that, you must be inside a **Row**, **Column** or **Stack** widget):

```
if (condition) ...[
    Widget1(),
    Widget2(),
  ],

// with else / else if:
if (condition1) ...[
    Widget1(),
    Widget2(),
  ]
else if(condition2)...[
    Widget3(),
    Widget4(),
]
else ...[
    Widget3(),
    Widget4(),
],
```

Comment: the multiple widget one t.i.l for me, thanks for this!

Answer (score 23):

You can simply use a conditional statement `a==b?c:d`

For example :

```
Container(
  color: Colors.white,
  child: ('condition')
  ? Widget1(...)
  : Widget2(...)
)
```

I hope you got the idea.

Suppose if there is no else condition you can use a SizedBox.shrink()

```
Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: ('condition')
       ? Widget1(...)
       : SizedBox.shrink()
    )
```

If it is a column no need to write `?:` operator

```
Column(
 children: <Widget>[
  if('condition')
    Widget1(...),
 ],
)
```

Comment: What if there is no else condition? In Columns, saying a==b?c:null will not work

Comment: You can simply use SizedBox.shrick() as the second widget. updating the answer.

Comment: If it is a column then you can use if condition directly without else case:

`if('condition') widget()'

Answer (score 15):

Aside from the ternary operator, you can also use `Builder` widget if you have synchronous operation that needs to be performed before the condition statement.

```
    Builder(builder: (context) {
      /// some non-async operation here ...
      if(someCondition) {
        return Text('A');
      }
      else {
        return Text('B');
      } 
    })
```

Comment: Great answer! If you have one if-else condition ternary operator should suffice but if you have multiple if-else if-else conditions or switch cases, the Builder widget should be an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 13):

Lol after months of using ?: I just find out that I can use this:

```
Column(
     children: [
       if (true) Text('true') else Text('false'),
     ],
   )
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is the solution.
I have fixed it. Here is the code

```
child: _status(data[index]["status"]),

Widget _status(status) {
  if (status == "3") {
    return Text('Process');
  } else if(status == "1") {
    return Text('Order');
  } else {
    return Text("Waiting");
  }
}
```

Comment: How to using it

Comment: I got like 5 different enum to return different widget :D hope I can use switch case :')

Answer (score 10):

Another alternative: for '`switch's`' like statements, with a lot of conditions, I like to use maps:

```
return Card(
        elevation: 0,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(1),
        child: conditions(widget.coupon)[widget.coupon.status] ??
            (throw ArgumentError('invalid status')));


conditions(Coupon coupon) => {
      Status.added_new: CheckableCouponTile(coupon.code),
      Status.redeemed: SimpleCouponTile(coupon.code),
      Status.invalid: SimpleCouponTile(coupon.code),
      Status.valid_not_redeemed: SimpleCouponTile(coupon.code),
    };
```

It's easier to add/remove elements to the condition list without touch the conditional statement.

Another example:

```
var condts = {
  0: Container(),
  1: Center(),
  2: Row(),
  3: Column(),
  4: Stack(),
};

class WidgetByCondition extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  WidgetByCondition(this.index);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return condts[index];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

if you use a list of widgets you can use this:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  bool notNull(Object o) => o != null;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var condition = true;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Provider Demo"),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          condition? Text("True"): null,
          Container(
            height: 300,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Text("Test")
          )
        ].where(notNull).toList(),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: condition? Text("True"): null, 
this does an error Asertion false in console, on runtime execution

Comment: @exequielc you must add .where(notNull).toList() and the end of the WidgetList and the method bool notNull(Object o) => o != null;. Try whole example...

Comment: As of Dart 2.3 to conditionally include a widget in a list you can use:
[Text("Hello"),  if(world) Text("World")]

Answer (score 6):

> A better way

```
 Column(
        children: [
            if (firstCondition == true) ...[
              DayScreen(),
            ] else if(secondCondition == true)...[
              StatsScreen(),
            ], else...[
              StatsScreen(),
            ],
        ],
     ),
```

Answer (score 5):

*With a button*

```
bool _paused = false;

CupertinoButton(
  child: _paused ? Text('Play') : Text('Pause'),
  color: Colors.blue,
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      _paused = !_paused;
    });
  },
),
```

Answer (score 4):

****You can also use conditions by using this method** **

```
 int _moneyCounter = 0;
  void _rainMoney(){
    setState(() {
      _moneyCounter +=  100;
    });
  }

new Expanded(
          child: new Center(
            child: new Text('\$$_moneyCounter', 

            style:new TextStyle(
              color: _moneyCounter > 1000 ? Colors.blue : Colors.amberAccent,
              fontSize: 47,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800
            )

            ),
          ) 
        ),
```

Comment: This is the most clear explanation to using conditions in attributes

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: I no longer recommend the solution I posted below because I realized that using this method, both the child for the true result and the child for the false result are built but only one is used, which unnecessarily slows the code.

---

PREVIOUS ANSWER:

In my app I created a `WidgetChooser` widget so I can choose between widgets without conditional logic:

```
WidgetChooser(
      condition: true,
      trueChild: Text('This widget appears if the condition is true.'),
      falseChild: Text('This widget appears if the condition is false.'),
    );
```

This is the source for the `WidgetChooser` widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class WidgetChooser extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool condition;
  final Widget trueChild;
  final Widget falseChild;

  WidgetChooser({@required this.condition, @required this.trueChild, @required this.falseChild});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (condition) {
      return trueChild;
    } else {
      return falseChild;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting! 

Answer (score 3):

This is great article and conversation.  I tried to use the ternary operator as described.  But the code didn't work resulting in an error as mentioned.

```
Column(children: [ condition? Text("True"): null,],);
```

The ternary example above is miss leading.  Dart will respond with an error that a null was returned instead of widget.  You can't return null.  The correct way will be to return a widget:

```
Column(children: [ condition? Text("True"): Text("false"),],);
```

In order for the ternary to work you need to return a Widget. If you don't want to return anything you can return a empty container.

```
Column(children: [ condition? Text("True"): Container(),],);
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ternary operator for conditional statements in dart, It's use is simple

```
(condition) ? statement1 : statement2
```

if the `condition` is true then the `statement1` will be executed otherwise `statement2`.

Taking a practical example

```
Center(child: condition ? Widget1() : Widget2())
```

Remember if you are going to use `null` as `Widget2` it is better to use `SizedBox.shrink()` because some parent widgets will throw an exception after getting a `null` child.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea whether it's a good practice, but I am using:

```
class StatmentExample extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return pageValue==1 ? Page1():pageValue== 2? Page2():pageValue==3 ? Page3():Page4();
  }
}
```

Comment: The new age answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using Map<String, Widget>

```
Map<String, Widget> pageSelector = {
"login": Text("Login"),
"home": Text("Home"),
}
```

and inside the build function i pass the key to the map like this

```
new Center(
 child: pageSelector["here pass the key"] ?? Text("some default widget"),
)
```

or another solution is to use simple function

```
Widget conditionalWidget(int numberToCheck){
 switch(numberToCheck){
   case 0: return Text("zero widget");
   case 1: return Text("one widget");
   case 2: return Text("two widget");
   case 3: return Text("three widget");
   default: return Text("default widget");
}
```

and inside the build function pass the number of widget or any other parameter to check

```
new Center(
 child: conditionalWidget(pageNumber),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion **Best and the cleanest way** which I prefer is to create an helper typedef function class **coditional_widget.dart**.

```
typedef IfWidget = List<Widget> Function(bool, Widget);
typedef IfElseWidget = Widget Function(bool, Widget, Widget);
typedef ElseEmptyWidget = Widget Function(bool, Widget);

IfWidget ifTrueWidget =
    (bool condition, Widget child) => [if (condition) child];

IfElseWidget ifElseWidget =
    (bool condition, Widget isTrueChild, Widget isFalseChild) =>
        condition ? isTrueChild : isFalseChild;

ElseEmptyWidget elseEmptyWidget = (bool condition, Widget isTrueChild) =>
    condition ? isTrueChild : const SizedBox.shrink();
```

How to use it

```
// IfWidget 
  ** Row/ Column / Wrap child etc.
   children: <Widget>[
      ...ifWidget(title != null, Text('Only Display for True Conditon')),
      ]

// elseEmptyWidget
  ** Row/ Column / Wrap child etc.
   children: <Widget>[
          
      elseEmptyWidget(title!=null,Text('Only Display for True Conditon')),
      ]



// ifElseWidget
      ** Row/ Column / Wrap child etc.
       children: <Widget>[
            ifElseWidget(true,Text('Only Display for True Conditon'),Text('Only Display for false Conditon')),
          ]
```

it's only a few you can add more

Answer (score 2):

You can use builder in following manning:
I have consider a condition where we can get image url as null, hence if null I show a shrink sizedbox as it has no property a completely void widget.

```
Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
  if (iconPath != null) {
    return ImageIcon(
      AssetImage(iconPath!),
      color: AppColors.kPrimaryColor,
    );
  } else {
    return SizedBox.shrink();
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Conditional rendering in Flutter can easily be done by [proviso](https://pub.dev/packages/proviso) package.
It has a comprehensive set of conditional widgets and builders to make a more readable and simpler conditional statement code.

The API & helpers consist of but not limited to:

**conditional widgets & builders:**

```
ConditionWidget(
  condition: starred,
  widget: Icon(
    Icons.favorite
  ),
  fallback: fallbackWidget
)

ConditionBuilder(
  condition: (_) => someCondition,
  trueBuilder: (_) => trueWidget,
  fallbackBuilder: (_) => fallbackWidget
)
```

**switch case conditions:**

```
SwitchCaseBuilder.widget<String>(
  context: context,
  condition: (_) => '1',
  caseBuilders: {'1': (_) => someWidget(), '2': (_) => someWidget()},
  fallbackBuilder: (_) => fallbackWidget,
);
```

**or even a conditional parent widget**

```
ConditionalWrap(
  shouldWrap: shouldWrapChildInParent,
  child: Container(),
  parentBuilder: (child) => Container(
    child: child,
  ),
)
```

API supports either a single or multiple widgets rendering.
You are welcome to give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid using if statements, you can use the Flutter `Visibility` widget

[See the documentation here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities :

1. if you are using one widget only

Solution=>

```
     Visibility(
       visible: condition == true, 
       child: Text(""),
      ),
    OR

     Offstage(
       offstage: condition == false, 
       child: Text(""),
     ),
```

2. if you are using two widgets or more

Solution=>

```
      bool _visibility = false;
     
      isVisible?
          Widget1 
           :
          WIdget2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an if statement  in a `Text()` widget, you can use the `Anonymous function` like so:

```
class ConditionalStatmentExample extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
     (() {
      if(true){
        return "return a string";
      }

      return "any other string when the condition is not met";
     })(),
     textAlign: TextAlign.center, );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
child: Container(
   child: isFile == true ? 
            Image.network(pathfile, width: 300, height: 200, fit: BoxFit.cover) : 
            Text(message.subject.toString(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
),
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
Widget showIf(bool shouldShow, Widget widget) {
if (shouldShow) {
  return widget;
} else {
  return Container();
}}
```

So when you want to show something with condition you do like say

```
Column(children: [showIf(myConditionIsTrue, myComplexWidget)])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Flutter Widget to conditionally wrap a subtree with a parent without breaking the code tree**

````
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

/// Conditionally wrap a subtree with a parent widget without breaking the code tree.
///
/// [condition]: the condition depending on which the subtree [child] is wrapped with the parent.
/// [child]: The subtree that should always be build.
/// [conditionalBuilder]: builds the parent with the subtree [child].
///
/// ___________
/// Usage:
/// ```dart
/// return ConditionalParentWidget(
///   condition: shouldIncludeParent,
///   child: Widget1(
///     child: Widget2(
///       child: Widget3(),
///     ),
///   ),
///   conditionalBuilder: (Widget child) => SomeParentWidget(child: child),
///);
/// ```
///
/// ___________
/// Instead of:
/// ```dart
/// Widget child = Widget1(
///   child: Widget2(
///     child: Widget3(),
///   ),
/// );
///
/// return shouldIncludeParent ? SomeParentWidget(child: child) : child;
/// ```
///
class ConditionalParentWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ConditionalParentWidget({
    Key key,
    @required this.condition,
    @required this.child,
    @required this.conditionalBuilder,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final bool condition;
  final Widget Function(Widget child) conditionalBuilder;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return condition ? this.conditionalBuilder(this.child) : this.child;
  }
}
````

Answer (score -2):

#### Simple way:

Use the **Builder** widget

```dart
Center(
    child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
        if (a == b) {
          return const Widget1();
        } else {
          return const Widget2();
         }
        },
   ),
)
```

Answer (score -6):

Only if vibrating widget

```
if(bool = true) Container(

child: ....

),

OR

if(bool = true) Container(

child: ....

) else new Container(child: lalala),
```