# Conditional padding inside Flutter widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, padding

I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62077216/3808307) answer for conditional color

I am trying to do the same for padding like so

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: isLogin ? 58.0 : 10.0),
)
```

it is not being accepted.

Thank you

Comment: that's because you used the keyword "const" but you're taking a variable consideration... a constant can't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
            padding: isLogin
                ? EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 58.0)
                : EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
```

**Edit:**

or just remove `const` like this.

```
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: isLogin ? 58.0 : 10.0),
```

You can read the usage of `const` from [here](https://news.dartlang.org/2012/06/const-static-final-oh-my.html).

Comment: Thank you very much