# Flutter Page not scrolling

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll

I have this flutter code

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:law_diary/widgets/customAppBar.dart';
import 'package:law_diary/widgets/sideBar.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: CalendarPage(),
  ));
}

class CalendarPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CalendarPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<CalendarPage> createState() => _CalendarPageState();
}

class _CalendarPageState extends State<CalendarPage> {
  DateTime today = DateTime.now();

  int currentMonth = DateTime.now().month;
  int currentYear = DateTime.now().year;

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> records = [];
  Map<DateTime, List<String>> events = {};
  bool isLoadingData = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    final String apiUrl =
        'https://legaldiary.000webhostapp.com/android/diary/dailyCalendar.php';
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(apiUrl),
        body: {
          'year': currentYear.toString(),
          'month': currentMonth.toString(),
        },
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        setState(() {
          records = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(json.decode(response.body));
          events = convertListToMap(records);
          print(events);
          isLoadingData = false;
        });

        // print(records);
        if (records.isNotEmpty) {
          records.forEach((record) {
            // print(record);
          });
        } else {
          print('No records found for the selected case ID.');
        }
      } else {
        print('API request failed with status code: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error: $error');
    }
  }

  Map<DateTime, List<String>> convertListToMap(
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> inputList) {
    Map<DateTime, List<String>> resultMap = {};

    for (Map<String, dynamic> map in inputList) {
      String dateString = map['caseDate'];
      DateTime timestamp = DateTime.parse(dateString).toLocal();

      String casesCount = map['cases_count']
          .toString(); // Ensure cases_count is treated as a string

      if (resultMap.containsKey(timestamp)) {
        resultMap[timestamp]!.add(casesCount);
      } else {
        resultMap[timestamp] = [casesCount];
      }
    }

    return resultMap;
  }

  void _onDaySelected(DateTime day, DateTime focusedDay) {
    setState(() {
      today = DateTime(day.year, day.month, day.day);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(),
      body: isLoadingData
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : content(),
    );
  }

  Widget content() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        children: [
          // Expanded(
          //   child: SingleChildScrollView(
          //     child:
          TableCalendar(
            locale: "en_IN",
            rowHeight: 80,
            headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
              formatButtonVisible: false,
              titleCentered: true,
              titleTextStyle:
                  TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              headerPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              leftChevronPadding:
                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 16),
              rightChevronPadding:
                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 16),
            ),
            availableGestures: AvailableGestures.all,
            selectedDayPredicate: (day) => isSameDay(day, today),
            focusedDay: today,
            firstDay: DateTime.utc(currentYear, currentMonth, 1),
            lastDay: DateTime.utc(currentYear + 1, 1, 31),
            onDaySelected: _onDaySelected,
            calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(
              defaultBuilder: (context, day, focusedDay) {
                for (DateTime d in events.keys) {
                  if (isSameDay(day, d)) {
                    List<String> casesCounts = events[d] ?? [];
                    String casesCountText = casesCounts
                        .join(', '); // Join cases_count values if multiple
                    return Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        // Customize day cell appearance
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                        border: isSameDay(day, today)
                            ? Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)
                            : Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              '${day.day}',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: isSameDay(day, today)
                                    ? Colors.white
                                    : Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.lightGreen.shade400,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                    10.0), // Adjust the border radius as needed
                              ),
                              child: Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.calendar_month_sharp,
                                    size: 14,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(width: 5),
                                  Text(
                                    casesCountText,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
          ),
          //   ),
          // ),
          SizedBox(height: 15),
          Text(
              'Selected Day: ' +
                  DateFormat('dd-MMM-yyyy').format(today).toString(),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
          Text(
            '${events[today]?.isNotEmpty ?? false ? 'Number of Cases: ${events[today]!.join(', ')}' : 'No cases found'}',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried everything but the page does not scroll.

In the portrait mode it does not need scrolling but when i rotate the screen to landscape mode, it needs scrolling but the page does not scroll.

i have tried using both listview and singlechildscrollview but nothing works

[Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49720332/how-to-use-conditional-statements-ternary-inside-a-flutter-widget)

I referred this link as well but nothing works.

Comment: did you get any error? Try to use `physics: NeverScrollPhysics()` instead `physics: ClampingScrollPhysics()' .

Comment: earlier i was not getting any error but this statement is giving error

Comment: okay I used physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), instead but still not scrolling

Comment: The calendar widget has scrolling mechanism that absorbs the swipe event, that's why the parent scroll view can't be scrolled

Comment: So there is no solution for the same ?

Answer (score 1):

Update -

I changed the following property of TableCalendar and it worked like a charm

`availableGestures: AvailableGestures.all,`

to

`availableGestures: AvailableGestures.none,`