# Is it safe to have a Widget class that returns a widget conditionally?

Tags: dart, flutter

Quite often I only want to draw a Widget based on a condition.

For example, I may be creating a component that displays a FadeIn.image but the image: may not be set in the CMS. In this case I want to ignore drawing the FadeIn.image and just return an empty container.

for context, I had done,

```
child: (someValue == null) ? new Container() : new LabelComponent(label: myStringLabel)
```

But this broke hot reload and I needed to replace with,
child: _createLabelComponent(myStringLabel),

```
Widget _createLabelComponent(String label)
{
  if(label == null) {
      return new Container();
    } else {
      return new LabelComponent(label: label) 
    }
}
```

Is the below safe to work and will not break hot reload? It seems to work at the moment but before I replace all my conditions with this Widget, I'd like some more feedback.

```
class ConditionalWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  final bool condition;
  final Widget conditionalWidget;

  ConditionalWidget(this.condition, this.conditionalWidget, {Key key});

  @override
  State createState() => new ConditionalWidgetState();

}

class ConditionalWidgetState extends State<ConditionalWidget> {

  ConditionalWidgetState();

  @override
  void initState()
  {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    if(widget.condition) {
      return widget.conditionalWidget;
    } else {
      return new Container();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's safe as long as it returns a widget. It's common to conditionaly return different widgets.

Comment: Your first code seems fine too. Maybe get rid of the parenthesis like this: child: someValue == null ? new Container() : new LabelComponent(label: myStringLabel)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer that is interesting. I was reading a thread on the reddit.com/r/flutterdev where someone mentioned ternary operators would break hot reload so I have been moving all my conditional code to functions. 

This did seem to stabilise the hot reload functionality using Intelli J and TBH it's a bit tidier, but a whole heap more code that essentially does the same thing - check a value and if null return a new Container()

Comment: There is a SO question about "functional widgets" where this is discussed. Only on my phone so no link.

Comment: I'm sure I've read that and just did had quick look again but nothing returned when looking for 'functional widgets' but I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713189/how-to-use-conditional-statement-within-child-attribute-of-a-flutter-widget-cen which is about conditional widgets. 

I am trying to solve hot reload problems rather than the best way to write conditional statements. Ternary would be the most efficient but as on a widget with too many, hot reload halts at 'Syncing files to device....'

Comment: followed by "Application finished." where it crashes

Answer (score 0):

Nothing magic here, `child` is a property of a `Container` class:
it is safe to use whatever expression returns a widget for `child` property, obviously also conditional expressions
`condition ? expr1 : expr2`.

If hot reload in broken check for other causes.

For example your code that break hot reload:

```
child: (someValue == null) ? new Container() : new LabelComponent(label: myStringLabel)
```

uses `someValue` and `myStringLabel`, whereas in `_createLabelComponent` there is only a `label` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
class StatmentExample extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text((() {
      if(true){
        return "tis true";}

      return "anything but true";
    })());
  }
}
```

wrap your statements in a function

```
(() {
  // your code here
}())
```