# if condition to run Widget at Container flutter

Tags: flutter

if condition when post.text == 1 
i setup Widget named exteranews

```
  Widget exteranews(BuildContext context) {
    double siz11 = 15.0 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 414.0;

      }
```

how to use if with that Container

```
 Container(
                                   if (checkothers)   child: exteranews(context),
                                ),
```

i set  `String checkothers = post.text;`
i read i have to setup Widget to use run exteranews() but how to use if condition with it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use conditional statement within child attribute of a Flutter Widget (Center Widget)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713189/how-to-use-conditional-statement-within-child-attribute-of-a-flutter-widget-cen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You may use `?` syntax
2. please make sure to put `Container()` so it will display nothing
   its easier to image Container() equals to `<div></div>` in html

```dart
Widget extraNews(BuildContext context) {
  double siz11 = 15.0 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 414.0;
  return Container();
}

class BaseScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  ///
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: checkothers == true ? extraNews(context) : Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , that's help very much