# How to show a container for 3 seconds

Tags: flutter

I have a container in which there are 2 fields. 1 is a percentage and the other is simple Text. What I need is I don't want to show the percentage container and when I click on the container it will show the percentage for 3 seconds only and then disappear, Can anyone please tell how it's possible?

Here is my code

```
int size = _questions.length;

void nextQuestion(){
  if(index < size - 1)
    setState(() {
      index++;
    });
  print(index);
}


double percentage1Calculate(){
  int wouldClick = int.parse(_questions[index]['wouldclick']);
  int ratherClick = int.parse(_questions[index]['ratherclick']);
  double percentage1 = wouldClick / (wouldClick + ratherClick) * 100;
  return percentage1;
}


        GestureDetector(
          child: Container(
            height: stackHeight * 0.5,
            width: stackWidth,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right: 10),
                    height: stackHeight * 0.1,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('${percentage1Calculate().toStringAsFixed(0)}%',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 23,
                            fontFamily: 'NewsCycle',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],

                    )
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  height: stackHeight * 0.4,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        child: Text(
                          _questions[index]['would'],
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 23,
                            fontFamily: 'NewsCycle',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

As in code i have wrapped a container in GestureDetector. And in container i have 2 container. both are showing text. What i need is when user click on gesturedetector then the 1st container show the value and after 3 seconds it will hide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start by making a conditional like `shouldShow` that determines when the container should be shown and then doing something like `if(shouldShow)` before the container in the column.

In the `onTap` callback of your `GestureDetector`, call `setState` and change the value of `shouldShow` to `true`. In `onTap` you should also start a new `Timer` with a `Duration` of 3 seconds with a callback that calls `setState` again and changes `shouldShow` to `false`.

`onTap` sample:

```
onTap: () {
  setState(() {
    shouldShow = true;
  });
  Timer timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
    setState(() {
      shouldShow = false;
    });
  });
}
```

Build method snippet:

```
child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    if(shouldShow)
    Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right: 10),
      height: stackHeight * 0.1,
      color: Colors.blue,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('${percentage1Calculate().toStringAsFixed(0)}%',
              style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 23,
              fontFamily: 'NewsCycle',
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    ),
    //Other container here
  ],
),
```

Comment: showing error on Timer. Need to import something for timer ?

Comment: method Timer isnt define for the class

Comment: You have to import `import 'dart:async';`

Comment: @ShahnazRaheem Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks its working can you please tell how can apply else condition ? as in this if shouldShow is true then it will show this container and if its false then to show other container Thanks again

Comment: Yeah it's possible with some modifications. Here is some reading on how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713189/how-to-use-conditional-statement-within-child-attribute-of-a-flutter-widget-cen

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample code

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  var showPercentage = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              // ==== THIS IF STATEMENT WILL TAKE CARE OF THE REST
              child:if (showPercentage) Text('Percentage widget'),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  showPercentage = !showPercentage;
                });
                Timer timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
                  setState(() {
                    showPercentage = false;
                  });
                });
              },
            ),
          Text('text widget'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This code will not work as the `GestureDetector` will disappear following a single use.

Comment: isn't that the whole point of question, and if one want to show the percentage again should call 
`setState(() {
                  showPercentage = true;
                });`
from some where else

Comment: The way you structured it makes it impossible to show the percentage again without rerunning the app.

Comment: It may work but its not what the OP is asking for and it has redundant code. Taking the `GestureDetector` outside of the `if` statement would have been a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

The flutter docs has a nice example of fading out a widget after 500 milliseconds by wrapping a Container with the `AnimatedOpacity` widget.

```
AnimatedOpacity(
  // If the widget is visible, animate to 0.0 (invisible).
  // If the widget is hidden, animate to 1.0 (fully visible).
  opacity: _visible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  // The green box must be a child of the AnimatedOpacity widget.
  child: Container(
    width: 200.0,
    height: 200.0,
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
);
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question.