# How can use if statement with Container widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, if-statement, containers

I want to use if statement with container widget like this code :

```
if (int.parse(m_id) > int.parse(cm_id) || int.parse(d_id) > 4)
    {
      Container(
         width: 0.23 * size,
         height: 0.23 * size,
         child: Image.asset('assets/images/days/day4k.png'),
     ),
}
```

But it gets error :

```
The element type 'Set<Container>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'
```

is there a way to fix this error ?

Comment: remove the braces

Comment: @Yann39 then if i have else statement after this?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot have an `else` statement, use another `if` or move the code into a function returning a widget.

Comment: Thanks alot i used if statement twice and it is worked

Comment: @Yann39 you can have an else statement, check out my answer

Comment: @ByteMe Oh sure sorry, was confused with something else, just tried and it indeed works, cheers !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use conditional statement within child attribute of a Flutter Widget (Center Widget)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713189/how-to-use-conditional-statement-within-child-attribute-of-a-flutter-widget-cen)

Comment: @Yann39 I get the answer Thanls alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Braces should not be used in if the `if statement` is inside a flutter widget

```dart
if (int.parse(m_id) > int.parse(cm_id) || int.parse(d_id) > 4)
      Container(
         width: 0.23 * size,
         height: 0.23 * size,
         child: Image.asset('assets/images/days/day4k.png'),
   ),
```

The above should work just fine

If you do happen do have an `if else statement`, you still won't employ the use of braces, just remove the `,` at the end of the of the first widget

```dart
if (int.parse(m_id) > int.parse(cm_id) || int.parse(d_id) > 4)
    Container(
       width: 0.23 * size,
       height: 0.23 * size,
       child: Image.asset('assets/images/days/day4k.png'),
    ) //no comma here
else
    Container(), //comma here
```

Also, If you have an `else if` statement, you would also approach it in the same way

```dart
if (int.parse(m_id) > int.parse(cm_id) || int.parse(d_id) > 4)
    Container(
       width: 0.23 * size,
       height: 0.23 * size,
       child: Image.asset('assets/images/days/day4k.png'),
    ) //no comma here
else if (condition here)
    Container() //no comma here
else
    Container(), //comma here
```

Comment: so if i have else statement after if, how can i put else?

Comment: I just added how to do it in an if else situation

Comment: You're welcome. I've also updated my answer to show how to do in an `else if` statement in case you need that in the future

Answer (score 0):

It's must works:

```
if (int.parse(m_id) > int.parse(cm_id) || int.parse(d_id) > 4)...[
    Container(
         width: 0.23 * size,
         height: 0.23 * size,
         child: Image.asset('assets/images/days/day4k.png'),
     ),
]
```

Comment: so  if i have else statement after if, how can i put else?

Comment: `else` not, but you can write code like this:
`if (!(int.parse(m_id) > int.parse(cm_id) || int.parse(d_id) > 4))...[
    this is like else
]`